# Communicating between C++ and C# in the same Metro project

Tags: microsoft-metro

In my metro application, I have two components one in C++ and another in C#. Can I communicate in between them to and fro? Any code samples or references on how to do this will be very helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is some [C++/CX code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh699871.aspx).  You can either write C++/CX directly instead of standard C++, or you can create wrappers around your standard C++.  Once you do this, your C# code can make calls to the C++ just as if was another C# component.

Specifically, what you're doing is turing your C++ component into a windows runtime component.  [Here's an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh441569.aspx) of C++ and Javascript, but consuming in C# is similar.